# What does おとこえしや mean?

Tags: parsing

This is a sentence from 『風の又三郎』 by 宮沢賢治.

> ところがその跡のようなものは、まだ百歩も行かないうちに、おとこえしや、すてきに背の高いあざみの中で、二つにも三つにも分かれてしまって、どれがどれやらいっこうわからなくなってしまいました。

My question is, what does おとこえしや mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [kind of plant](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B7), オトコエシ, plus the non-exhaustive listing particle や.